# How to pass callback + context to C function from Go using cgo

Tags: go, function-pointers, cgo

I'm trying to use Apple's [DNSServiceQueryRecord](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dnssd/1804747-dnsservicequeryrecord?language=objc) from Go, so I have access to the resource records. The function takes a callback that I have not been able to make it work.

I'm trying to pass a function as the callback context, so it can communicate back the end of the DNS lookup. Go code calls `queryDNS`, which calls `DNSServiceQueryRecord`, which later calls `goCallback`, which is supposed to call the context function. This is the relevant part of my app code:

```golang
//go:build darwin

package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dns_sd.h>

extern void goCallback(DNSServiceRef sdRef, DNSServiceFlags flags, uint32_t interfaceIndex,
    DNSServiceErrorType errorCode, char* fullname, uint16_t rrtype, uint16_t rrclass,
    uint16_t rdlen, void* rdata, uint32_t ttl, void* context);

static DNSServiceErrorType queryDNS(DNSServiceRef *sdRef, DNSServiceFlags flags, uint32_t interfaceIndex,
    const char *fullname, uint16_t rrtype, uint16_t rrclass,
    void *context) {
    return DNSServiceQueryRecord(sdRef, flags, interfaceIndex, fullname, rrtype, rrclass,
    (DNSServiceQueryRecordReply)goCallback, context);
}
*/
import "C"

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "time"
    "unsafe"

    "golang.org/x/net/dns/dnsmessage"
)

//export goCallback
func goCallback(sdRef C.DNSServiceRef, flags C.DNSServiceFlags, interfaceIndex C.uint32_t,
    errorCode C.DNSServiceErrorType, fullname *C.char, rrtype C.uint16_t, rrclass C.uint16_t,
    rdlen C.uint16_t, rdata unsafe.Pointer, ttl C.uint32_t, context unsafe.Pointer) {
    (*(*func())(context))()
    fmt.Println("callback", errorCode)
}

func queryCNAME(ctx context.Context, qname string) (string, error) {
    var sdRef C.DNSServiceRef

    cQname := C.CString(qname)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cQname))
    done := make(chan struct{})
    callback := func() {
        fmt.Println("callback")
        done <- struct{}{}
    }
    callbackPtr := unsafe.Pointer(&callback)
    var pinner runtime.Pinner
    pinner.Pin(callbackPtr)
    defer pinner.Unpin()
    fmt.Println("starting")
    // See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dnssd/1804747-dnsservicequeryrecord?language=objc
    queryErr := C.queryDNS(&sdRef, 0, 0,
        cQname, C.uint16_t(dnsmessage.TypeCNAME), C.uint16_t(dnsmessage.ClassINET),
        callbackPtr)
    fmt.Println("returned")
    if queryErr != 0 {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("failed to start DNS query: %v", queryErr)
    }
    defer C.DNSServiceRefDeallocate(sdRef)
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)

    <-done

    return "", nil
}
```

When I run, I get:

```
go run .
starting
panic: runtime error: cgo argument has Go pointer to unpinned Go pointer

goroutine 19 [running]:
main.queryCNAME.func3(0x102d18728?, 0x14000116020?, 0x1400027dbd0?)
        /Users/fortuna/code/gio-test/sysresolver_darwin.go:79 +0x60
main.queryCNAME({0x14003e849c0?, 0x102bcb239?}, {0x14003e8c1e3, 0x3})
        /Users/fortuna/code/gio-test/sysresolver_darwin.go:79 +0x188
main.main.func1.1()
        /Users/fortuna/code/gio-test/main.go:88 +0x5e0
main.main.func1()
        /Users/fortuna/code/gio-test/main.go:153 +0x1c
created by main.main in goroutine 1
        /Users/fortuna/code/gio-test/main.go:37 +0x24
exit status 2
```

I've tried using the `runtime.Pinner`, but it didn't work. How can I make it work?

By the way, I also had to declare the `queryDNS` C function `static`, otherwise the linker would complain with duplicate symbol, no idea why.

Comment: You can’t pass a go function directly to C, they have different calling conventions. https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2019/passing-callbacks-and-pointers-to-cgo/

Comment: I am not. DNSServiceQueryRecord is taking the "extern void goCallback" in C. The `callbackPtr` is supposed to be a `void *` context.